# Timestamp error when trying to import .dmp data postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, dump, pgadmin

I have a dump of a huge database (around 30gb) that I'm trying to import to pg admin 3. 
There are around 600 tables in the database - and it all works fine until the last ~50 tables are reached...
I'm importing the dump via the cmd prompt

Here's the error message I get:

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for timestamp: Â»SÂ«
KONTEXT:  COPY XXXX, Line 100970, Spalte odb_created_at: Â»SÂ«

I really have no idea how to handle this error since I cannot open the script in any editor

BR

Comment: Create an SQL dump with `pg_restore -f sqlfile -a -t tablename dumpfile` and show the offending line.

Comment: What is the exact command line you use to restore the dump?

Comment: This is the cmd line I used to create a dmp: pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 -d dbname > path\name.dmp